# UITableView data is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I created a custom class ("customClass") that is a subclass of `UIView`. I then added a `tableView` to it's subview, and created an `array` for the `datasoucre`. I set the `delegate` and `datasource` to self. Then in the `storyboard`, I set a `UIViews` class to `customClass`.

Then in the mainVC class, I set an array to some `strings` and set that `array` to the array in the customClass. When I run the app, it doesn't crash or give me any errors, but I don't see any results in the `tableView`

Here's how it's setup in `mainVC.m`:

```
self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", @"Fourth", @"Fith", @"Sixths", @"Seventh", nil];
self.myView.resultArray = self.myArray;
[self.myView.tableView reloadData];
```

Here is the code in customClass:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setupTableView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupTableView
{
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.resultArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:self.resultArray [indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

When I run the app, I don't see any results in the `tableView` although I do see a `tableView` shown. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

**Edit**

Just realized, `cellForRow` doesn't even get called! I did a `reloadData`, and it still didn't get called.

Comment: you have to set data source and delegates after allocation of tableview object.(here, it seems like no datasource detected for your tableview object)

Comment: is everything being called. can you NSLog the correct values at each point?

Comment: I got it working thanks to @Jaleel Nazir. But thanks anyway

Comment: @Jessica: Check the array count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> initWithFrame: - It is recommended that you implement this method. You
>   can also implement custom initialization methods in addition to, or
>   instead of, this method.
>
> initWithCoder: - Implement this method if you load your view from an
>   Interface Builder nib file and your view requires custom
>   initialization.
>
> initWithCoder is called much before init and viewDidLoad methods

In MainVC

```
viewClass *vc = [[viewClass alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
vc.resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", @"Fourth", @"Fith", @"Sixths", @"Seventh", nil];
[vc.tableView reloadData];
[self.view addSubview:vc];
```

In Custom Class...

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        [self setupTableView];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setupTableView
{

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self addSubview:self.tableView]; // Datasource and delegate after alloc init
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.resultArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:self.resultArray [indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Register Cell when using Custom UItableviewCell, Otherwise don't use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];, it will crash.

Comment: Your right, it just crashed. What do you mean register cell. Do I have to create a whole new file, or can I just do the initWithStyle?

Comment: when you not using custom cell , comment registerclass line and use  this... UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; while using custom cell , in registerclass use your custom cell class

Comment: I'm not using a custom cell, so I did `if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }` and it crashes with the error of: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell. must register nib or a class for the id...

Comment: See setupTableView in my answer....  
when you not using custom cell , comment registerclass line and use this... UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; while using custom cell , in registerclass use your custom cell class –

Comment: You Got it... Just study and Experiment when to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier  and  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath: , what is register class,  what is  initWithFrame: , what is initWithCoder:  that helps very much.  when to use? how o use ? All the Best.

Answer (score -1):

You can set customClass's backgroundColor to red,and then check the customClass is added on the mainVC's view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I set the color, and I see it. The only problem is the datasource. (I think this should have been a comment. :)